# Visual basic delete duplicates keep unique

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to delete rows that have duplicate cell contents and keep rows with unique values.  Ex.:

```
R1  A
R2  A
R3  B
R4  C
R5  C
```

In this scenario, only B is unique.  Both A and C are not unique as they occur more than once.  (Most solutions found by searching incorrectly delete duplicates, thus creating unique values A & B.)

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried using one of those algorithms you've found, but inverting the delete logic?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good place to just ask for code.  If you demonstrate effort then someone will probably show you how to solve your problem.  Finding code that is almost identical to the code you need without trying to adapt that code does not count as effort for most people here.

You need to design your solution then consider how to slot the code you have found into that design.  There are many routes to a good design but I normally suggest people start by asking themselves: “How would I do this manually?”

In your example list, the rows are sorted on the target column.  Is that true of the real data or could you sort the real data by the target column?

If the data is not sorted and cannot be sorted then the problem becomes more difficult although not impossible.  In this situation, I would recommend:

1. Find an empty column to the right of your data.
2. Fill that column with row numbers.
3. Sort by the target column.
4. Delete duplicates as shown below.
5. Sort by the column of row numbers
6. Delete the column of row numbers.

The algorithm below assumes the rows are sorted.

If you were going to delete rows, you would probably start at the top.  This would mean that every time you deleted some rows, every row below would have to be moved up including all the rows you would later decide to delete.  It is faster to start at the bottom.  I suggest you would do something like this:

```
Set RowCrnt to number of bottom row
Do While RowCrnt > 1
  If target column of RowCrnt is equal to target column of RowCrnt-1 Then
    ‘ Have found the bottom row of a block to be deleted
    Set RowBlockBottom = RowCrnt
    RowCrnt = RowCrnt - 1
    Do While target column of RowCrnt is equal to target column of RowBlockBottom
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt - 1
    Loop
    Delete rows RowCrnt + 1 to RowBlockBottom
    ‘ RowCrnt points at the next row to be matched against the row above
  Else
    RowCrnt = RowCrnt - 1
  End If
Loop
```

Try “running” the pseudo code above on paper.  Think about how I have produced this code.  Look for any deliberate or accidental errors.  This is an easy design technique that works for most simple problems.  If you can master this technique you will be ready to tackle many future problems without needing help.

I expect the code you have found will include statements that will do everything in the pseudo code above.  Try building the macro you need by replacing the pseudo code with the relevant statements.  **Don’t forget to save a copy of your data before testing the macro.**

If the code does not work as you require and you cannot see why, post it here with an explanation of the different between what it does and what you want it to do.  Someone will help.

Good luck.

Comment: I only know a little VB and only use it intermittently.  Here is the code I have that works exactly as desired, but by pulling in an existing list, comparing and leaving "unique" values.  (Have another one that works using nested conditional statements.  Shorter, but much slower.)

Comment: @sparcboy.  You say "Here is the code" but I cannot find any code.

Comment: I'm new to this website.  I tried posting the code but it's too many characters and not allowed. Time to edit comment ran out.  Frustrating! The code I have works perfectly, but it seems it could be much more concise.  Where and / or how can I post it?  (P.S. I'm in effect at "Visual Basic for Dummies" level.)

Comment: The limit for an answer is 30,000 characters and I assumed it was the same for a question.  Even with comments, I am surprised a routine to meet your requirement is so big.  If the code does what you want, what are you asking?  There are free sites where you can post files of any size.  You can then post a link here.